# OpportunityTeamMember Trigger fail to trigger when adding Opportunity Team via "Add Default Team"

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity-teams

I created a trigger on OpportunityTeamMember. But when I insert Team Member using 'Add Default Team', the trigger is not firing. Am I missing something or this is expected behavior?

Comment: That is not the issue. It's not Triggering at all. Not a single debug is being generated in logs. When I add via 'Add', Trigger working fine.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question so that it is easier to help, though this may be due to how the 'Add Default Team' function works.

Comment: Well, I found a separate thread [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218997/trigger-on-opportunityteammember-is-not-firing-when-opportunity-owner-is-changed?rq=1) with almost same issue mentioning the same issue. There are some more cases where the Trigger doesn't fire. The code is not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "as designed" behavior.

From [Considerations for Customizing Opportunity Teams](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_teamselling.htm&type=5):

> Validation rules and Apex triggers aren’t supported when a user adds his or her default opportunity team on an opportunity.

This is one of the relatively small number of operations on which triggers are not supported.

Comment: Great to hear that, but what if there's a Process Builder which is also getting failed to Trigger. The documentation does not mention Flows to be not supported.

Comment: I am not familiar with any documentation on using Process Builder with Default Opportunity Teams, but I would be astonished if Process Builder were supported and Apex Triggers were not in that situation.

Comment: I just got word from Salesforce and they have confirmed that Apex Class/Process Builders/ Workflow Rules/ Validation Rule won't work. The only workaround I was able to find is to use custom Button to Execute JS and SForce to do the automation.